If I used to be a Christian does that mean I committed shirk and now Allah won't forgive me?
Before coming to Islam I was trying to find God so I studied alot of religions some with positive messages and other with not so desirable ones including satanism so does that mean I committed shirk and even tho now I'm submitting I still won't be forgiven ? Also another part is I know when you become Muslim you past sins are wiped away but does that not count for shirk?

"Before coming to Islam I was trying to find God" ... could not stop a comment. I really hope you have not stopped and are still trying, at least for a deeper understanding. Seeking God is not like a tin cup from winning a sports game, that, once you have it, you store in your cupboard. You have been through different religions, so you know the dangers and temptations. Don't sit lazy, your study has just started.

That Allah does not forgive Shirk is for when someone passes away while being Mushrik, not after repent and submitting to Islam. Otherwise, most companions of the holy prophet PBUHH who were martyred in Islam's early wars should be sentenced for being Mushrik for a while in the early portions of their lives.
